# Display child records in child grid upon selecting a row in parent grid in axapta

Tags: axapta

How to display child records in child grid upon selecting a row in parent grid in axapta 2009.

I have dragged a parent grid and child grid on a new form and successfully display data from parent & child tables. But would like the child records 2 be displayed only when the parent row is selected. Please let me know if oyu have any suggestions or if you have references of articles.  It will be really appreciated.
Thanks
N

Answer (score 1):

[Joining Data Sources on Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa608858%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)

Set the JoinSource property of your child datasource to the name of the parent datasource.

Answer (score 0):

NP, this is a programming forum...not a "tell me how to do it" forum.

Look at Forms\SalesTable to see how the sales table shows header records and child (SalesLine) records.  Also look at the DataDictionary\Tables\SalesTable and DataDictionary\Tables\SalesLine.